# Add file to Listview Items

Tags: c#, wpf, file

Im doing a simple documentation management project which is like secretary usage. I'm keeping data in ms access. In main windows I have a listview which is listing existing document details. Also, I need add a file (excel,word,powerpoint,pdf) to document details in selected computer files. If a document has a file user would be add file for this document while it's creating like I said. I don't have any idea. Can you give me any document to do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

Save the document to a byte[] and display the document name in the list that way you will know what you have.